# Удалить все "/" в переменной $a, кроме той, которая находится в самом конце переменной

Tags: php

Допустим, у нас есть такая переменная:

```
$a = "user/category/link/buy/"
```

Нам нужно из этого сделать такой вариант:

```
$a = "usercategorylinkbuy/"
```

Наработки:

```
strtr($a, array('/' => ''));
//Удаляет абсолютно все / внутри переменной
```

Причем если в переменной $a изначально не будет "/", то он **не должен** добавляться в конец.

Comment: Обожаю такой подход:

       strtr($a, array('/' => ''));
       // патсаны, я типа пытался, че?

Comment: [Регулярные выражения][1]


  [1]: http://php.su/functions/?preg-replace

Comment: На перле это было бы `s|/([^/]+)(?=/)|\1|g`

Answer (score 1):

Если вам известно, что в конце переменной точно есть /, тогда смысл имеет такой код:

```
if(substr($a,-1)=="/")
{
$a = str_replace("/","",$a);
$a .= "/";
}
else
{
$a = str_replace("/","",$a);
}
```

Comment: Немного по-индийски, но будет желание - оптимизируешь...Это так, на скорую руку

Answer (score 1):

Всё гораздо проще.

```
trim($a, '/');
```

Правда он и в начале обрежет, если в начале нужно сохранить '/' то можно сделать так:

```
'/'.trim($a, '/');
```